# Unable to get push notification in the Android app using the firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making use of Firebase account and In that I have selected Cloud messaging. Through that option, I can send any message from firebase to my Android emulator.

The token is generated and I have pasted it into the firebase but it doesn't show any push notification.

there are no errors as well.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }

                        // Get new FCM registration token
                        String token = task.getResult();

                        // Log and toast
                        String msg = token;
                        Log.d("Token:", msg);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the FirebaseMessagingService? if yes share it to me please .

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reaching out to me.. I solved it. It was a silly mistake. I needed to close the app and go to home page. It's because if you're using the application then you won't be able to get the push notifications. Thanks again. Appreciate it.

Comment: You need to show notification programmatically when user using the app.